# How to add a different title (Hover-Text) for each value of a slider element without using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, hover, slider, dom-events

I was looking online on how to create a different hover message for each slider value, but I couldn't find something that does not use JQuery.

```html
<!-- Slider Input -->
<input type="range" id="mySlider" value="0" min="0" max="10"
  style="width:80%;" title="This should change every value."/>
```

What I'm trying to do is to when the user hovers the slider (bullet); the hover message displays something simple. See examples below:

Example 1: value = 1 -> Hover Msg: "Stage 1 ..."

Example 2: value = 2 -> Hover Msg: "Stage 2 ..."

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign an event listener to the change event and then update the `title` attribute of the slider, like this...

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("mySlider");

function onSliderChange() {
  slider.title = "Stage " + slider.value;
}

slider.addEventListener("change", onSliderChange);

onSliderChange();
```

```html
<input type="range" id="mySlider" value="0" min="0" max="10" style="width:80%;"/>
```

The `title` attribute is the tooltip, or hint text for an element, and I trigger the change event handler once at the start, so it initialises the title with "Stage 0"

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for your answer @Archer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Misunderstood what you meant by a slider, try this if you want plain javascript:

```
let input = Document.getElementbyId("mySlider");
input.addEventListener("mouse up", (e) => {
    if(e.currentTarget.value === 1){
        console.log("Hover Msg: Stage 1 ...") 
        // or you could display message in an elsewhere tag
    }
    else if(e.currentTarget.value === 2){
        console.log("Hover Msg: Stage 2 ...")
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by position?

Comment: when you said slider I assumed you meant an on of slider? what did you mean?

Comment: I definitely didn't mean on-off button. its an input element of type slider. Just forget it dude.